# Some issues with a basic PHP calendar script

Tags: php, calendar

I have this simple PHP calendar template (starts from Monday instead of Sunday, since I'm italian)

```
<?php
$date = strtotime("2011-05-19");
$monthNames = Array("Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre");
$cMonth = date("n", $date);
$cYear = date("Y", $date);
?>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
      <caption>
      <?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?>
      </caption>
      <tr>
        <th>l</th>
        <th>m</th>
        <th>m</th>
        <th>g</th>
        <th>v</th>
        <th>s</th>
        <th>d</th>
      </tr>
      <?php 
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday']-1;
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) { ?>
      <tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php   if($i < $startday) { ?>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><?php echo ($i - $startday + 1); ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php   if(($i % 7) == 6 ) { ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php }
?>
    </table>
```

Despite this "spaghetti code" it's simple and... almost working
I only have two issues (please change the $date value and look yourself):

1. if last day of the month is NOT last day of the week there are some missing table cells at the end of the calendar
2. some months don't start from 1 (i.e. try with $date = strtotime("2011-05-15");)

Any help, please?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: This sounds less like a question and more like just an unfinished implementation. If you're missing table cells before the start of the month (as in when the month does not start on Sunday) or at the end (as in when the month does not end on Saturday), then add them. Test for those conditions and add the appropriate table cells. For instance, many calendars will add a grayed-out style to days for the previous or next months as a visual indicator that they are not "current".

Comment: Jim, if I could add cells at the beginning and at the end of the table I didn't write a question for help: I have no clue on how to do this (and, anyway, seems that you read very "en passant" my question: my week starts from Monday and ends on Sunday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, in an effort to not reinvent the wheel I would use a localized calendar plugin such as [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Then displaying a calendar in Italian is as simple as:

```
$("#calendarDiv").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["it"]);
$("#calendarDiv").datepicker("setDate", "19/05/2011");
```

This calendar (localized to Italian) starts days of the week on Monday (Lunedi) and alters the default date format to the expected day/month/year common to the more sane countries.

Now, recognizing that using external plugins is not always a viable option, you could expand out the PHP to render your calendar like so (this block would appear after the header row you're currently using for week names):

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,0,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];

for ($i = 0; $i <= ($maxday + $startday); $i++)
{
    if(($i % 7) == 0 )
        echo "<tr>";

    if($i < $startday)
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    else
        echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>" . 
            ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";

    if(($i == ($maxday + $startday)) && (($i % 7) > 0))
    {
        $spareDays = (7 - ($i % 7)) - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < $spareDays; $i++)
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        break;
    }
    else if(($i % 7) == 6 )
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

I have made several adjustments to your example to correct the start and end day to make the view of the calendar appear identical to the one rendered by the jQuery UI Datepicker, although depending on how your instance of PHP is localized on your server, they may need to be adjusted back (see dmikester1's answer for an example). My implementation is fairly basic, but I wanted to keep it semantically similar to your original example.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line by removing the -1 seems to fix the problem #2:

```
$startday = $thismonth['wday']-1;
```

OK, that fix for #1 didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, the solution for #1 is ok but it starts on sunday this way (and I need it to start on monday); the solution for #1 doesn't works :-( seems that the condition $i > $maxday+1 is never reached

Comment: It starts on Sunday because the month of May in 2011 started on a Sunday.  You can't change that.